# (UWP) When SplitView pane is open, interaction with the rest of UI is not allowed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

The PERFECT example of what I need is in the Groove Music app. When the SplitView pane is open (in overlay mode), you are still allowed to interact with the rest of the UI (clicking other buttons, etc., and even when you hover your mouse over controls that are outside of the pane, they are highlighted as normal).

In my app, NOTHING is clickable outside of the pane area (besides the 3 system buttons in the top right area of window). But once you click outside the area of the pane, it closes. ONLY at that point can you interact with the UI as usual again.

I searched through the SplitView's property list to see if I was missing something, but still haven't figured out what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :]

Comment: Unable to reproduce what it is you say happens in Groove Music app. When in overlay mode it operates as designed where only the panel is accessible. clicking anywhere outside of the panel will close it as designed. Review the available states for the panel.

Comment: Of course "clicking" outside of the panel will close it. The issue is that the rest of the UI "freezes" (so to speak) in my app when the pane is open.

Comment: In Groove, if you hover your mouse over other icons (play button, etc), they will highlight as normal. Nothing in the background is frozen.

I need the rest of the UI to be in that exact UNFROZEN state. The big issue here is that if I click on an icon outside of the pane, nothing will happen. The user should be able to interact with the rest of the UI even when the pane is open. They shouldn't have to first close the pane (which requires a click), and only then be able to click to another tab or something... Get me?

Comment: It is not frozen. It is under a touch target which does not allow you to interact with it. Nothing outside of the panel reacts to mouse when panel is open in overlay mode.

Comment: Ok found a state where I was able to recreate the what you described. It depends on how wide the window is. When the panel is in CompactOverlay you get the behavior you describe. You are able to interact with the bottom bar when in that state.

Comment: Nobody has an answer on fixing this one?

Comment: What is there to fix? It looks like it is all by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you're describing is by design. If the `DisplayMode` property of a `SplitView` is set either to `SplitViewDisplayMode.Overlay` or `SplitViewDisplayMode.CompactOverlay` and when the `SplitView` is opened, rest of the UI is inaccessible. To have it opened all the time and let user interact with the rest of the UI, you have to use either `SplitViewDisplayMode.Inline` or `SplitViewDisplayMode.CompactInline`.

For more info, see the [`Split​View​Display​Mode` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitviewdisplaymode).